# React Select - how to type check its onChange handler

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

I'm currently building a design system in React TypeScript and for the Dropdown component have decided to use React Select to provide most of the functionality.

I've created a wraparound component called `<Dropdown />` and have created some custom components for React Select's internal sub-components, such as the Option and Menu. I'm positioning a Checkbox before each Option in the Menu and at the top of the Menu is a Select All button.

Here's my custom component for React Select's Menu subcomponent where I'm trying to call the Select's onChange method and pass it all options in order to select them all:

```
const DropdownMultiOptionMenu = (menuProps: MenuProps<OptionType>) => {
  const { children, options, selectProps } = menuProps;
  return (
    <components.Menu {...menuProps}>
      <button
        onClick={() => selectProps.onChange(options as MultiValue<OptionType>, 'select-value')}
      >
        Select all
      </button>
      {children}
    </components.Menu>
  );
};
```

I'm currently getting a TypeScript error for the 'select-value' parameter that I'm passing in to the onChange handler:

**Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ActionMeta'**

However, when I read React Select's documentation, they tell me that the second parameter of an onChange handler is an actionMeta type and the options given are all strings:

https://react-select.com/advanced#action-meta

Any ideas?

Here's the full code for the Dropdown:

```
import clsx from 'clsx';
import {
  default as ReactSelect,
  components,
  MenuProps,
  OptionProps,
  MultiValue
} from 'react-select';
import { Checkbox } from '../checkbox';
import styles from './index.module.css';

type OptionType = {
  value: string;
  label: string;
};

export interface DropdownProps {
  isMulti: boolean;
  options: OptionType[];
}

const DropdownMultiOption = (optionProps: OptionProps<OptionType>) => {
  const { children, isSelected } = optionProps;
  return (
    <components.Option {...optionProps}>
      <Checkbox
        id="multi-option"
        label={children?.toString()}
        value={children?.toString()}
        checked={isSelected}
        readOnly
      />
    </components.Option>
  );
};

const DropdownMultiOptionMenu = (menuProps: MenuProps<OptionType>) => {
  const { children, options, selectProps } = menuProps;
  return (
    <components.Menu {...menuProps}>
      <button
        onClick={() => selectProps.onChange(options as MultiValue<OptionType>, 'select-value')}
      >
        Select all
      </button>
      {children}
    </components.Menu>
  );
};

const Dropdown = ({ options, isMulti, ...rest }: DropdownProps) => (
  <ReactSelect
    classNames={{
      control: () => styles['c-dropdown'],
      menu: () => styles['c-dropdown__menu'],
      multiValue: () => styles['c-dropdown__multi-value'],
      option: () => styles['c-dropdown__option']
    }}
    closeMenuOnSelect={!isMulti}
    components={
      isMulti ? { Option: DropdownMultiOption, Menu: DropdownMultiOptionMenu } : undefined
    }
    isMulti={isMulti}
    hideSelectedOptions={false}
    options={options}
    unstyled
    {...rest}
  />
);

Dropdown.defaultProps = {};

export default Dropdown;
```

I've tried typecasting the 'select-value' string as type ActionMeta<OptionType>, but this caused a further TypeScript error which suggested this was not the right course of action.

**UPDATE:**

Have applied suggestions by @Peter Mortensen but still getting an error which I've added as a comment in the code below:

```
const DropdownMultiOptionMenu = (menuProps: MenuProps<OptionType>) => {
  const { children, selectProps, options } = menuProps;
  const action: ActionMeta<OptionType> = 'select-option'; // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ActionMeta<OptionType>'
  return (
    <components.Menu {...menuProps}>
      <button onClick={() => selectProps.onChange(options as MultiValue<OptionType>, action)}>
        Select all
      </button>
      <CheckboxGroup>{children}</CheckboxGroup>
    </components.Menu>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation you just sent, you can see that:

> React Select exposes a variety of eventListeners to you via props. The onchange function prop now has the following signature. (value: ValueType, action: ActionType) => undefined;
>
> The action argument is a string with the following possible values
>
> 'select-option': Selecting an option from the list
> 'deselect-option': (Multiple) Deselecting an option from the list
> 'remove-value': (Multiple) Removing a selected option with the remove button
> 'pop-value': Removing options using backspace
> 'set-value': Calling setValue from a component without an action
> 'clear': Removing all selected options with the clear button
> 'create-option': (Creatable) Creating a new option

There isn't any `select-value` in `ActionType`.

Additionally, for the future, you can press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> if you are using Visual Studio Code in order to see the suggestions that match the Type.

**Or:**

<s>Set the action into a variable and assign its type.
Something like this:</s>

```
const action:ActionType = 'select-option' // Or any of the actions you want
```

**EDIT:**

My bad, I had the Type set wrong. Check this [documentation](https://react-select.com/typescript#onchange) for the correct Types.

> If you have a single-select you can type onChange like this:
>
> const onChange = (option: Option | null, actionMeta:
> ActionMeta) => {    ... } If you have a multi-select you can
> type onChange like this:
>
> const onChange = (option: readonly Option[], actionMeta:
> ActionMeta) => {    ... } The actionMeta parameter is
> optional. ActionMeta is a union that is discriminated on the action
> type. Take a look at at types.ts in the source code to see its full
> definition.

Something like this should work:

```
import { ActionMeta, MenuProps, OptionProps } from 'react-select'


const DropdownMultiOptionMenu = (menuProps: MenuProps<OptionProps>) => {
  const { children, selectProps, options } = menuProps;
  const action: ActionMeta<OptionProps> = {
    action:'select-option',
    // Add the rest of the implementation as needed
    // I added the optional chaining just to show which attributes 
    // are required and which are optional
    option:...,
    name?:...,
    removedValue?:...,
    removedValues?:...
  }
  
  return (
    <components.Menu {...menuProps}>
      <button onClick={() => selectProps.onChange(options as MultiValue<OptionType>, action)}>
        Select all
      </button>
      <CheckboxGroup>{children}</CheckboxGroup>
    </components.Menu>
  );
};
```

Comment: Re *"you can press Command + I"*: Only if you are willing and/or able to contribute to [Apple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Inc.)'s 50% profit margin.

Comment: HI @PeterMortensen, thanks for the suggestion. I've tried it out and updated my question to show what i tried but I'm still getting an error which I've left as a comment above.

Comment: @JamesHowell Where are you importing `ActionMeta` from? It is supposed to be `ActionType` as per the documentation.

Comment: Would you mind sending the link over for the relevant page for importing `ActionType`? Currently getting "Module '"react-select"' has no exported member 'ActionType'."

Comment: Is there any chance you could edit the code snippet below "Update:" in my question to show me the error of my ways. I'm calling an onChange handler whereas the docs show a function definition. I can't seem to just declare it as documented and pass the function reference to selectProps.onChange because the function signature is expecting two parameters. So I think I need to structure it as I have above. But potentially I need to change the value of my action variable so that its something other than just a string. And thanks for the help. Much appreciated.